# Static ViewHolder and getting context when using with RecyclerView

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use a recycler view and handle on click event. I've read various methods of handling onClick event on a recycler view item like :

1. Define the click listener inside the view holder class itself.
2. Define the click listener in onCreateViewHolder().
3. Define an interface and then go from there (seems like too much work).

So my first question is which option is better?
I'm currently using the first method and if defining the click listener in the view holder class itself is the way to go, then how do I use the context from the adapter as the view holder class is static.

Basically, I want to have a static view holder and on click event, open a new Activity for which I need the context.

UPDATE : Adding adapter and ViewHolder code.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Job> jobs;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Job> jobs) {
        mContext = context;
        this.jobs = jobs;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);

        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(WorkExperienceAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
            //bindViewHolder code
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return jobs.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @InjectView(R.id.current)
        TextView mCurrent;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.inject(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first question, which approach is better, would yield primarily opinion based answers, which are unfit for SO format.

Comment: Yes but I wanted to know if there is any performance difference when it comes to comparing the first two methods.

Answer (score 9):

In the view holder constructor we get the object of View class. You can use that object to get the context like:

```
class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public Holder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    Context context = itemView.getContext();
   }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I actually tried this method but it doesn't work because         `itemView.getContext()` doesn't return an activity context, and hence it's not possible to start another activity using it.

Comment: What about setting listener in onBindViewHolder() method?

Comment: @user2558050 `itemView.getContext()` returns a `Context`, so use it for calling `startActivity()`

Comment: Yes I could actually do that, but I think it should be done on `onCreateViewHolder()` rather than `onBindViewHolder()` because I think registering a new listener every time a view is reused in `onBindViewHolder()` could affect performance, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @pskink I tried using the `Context` object returned by `itemView.getContext()` to start an activity, but got a runtime exception saying `android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?`

Comment: @user2558050 how are you creating the `View`s inside your `ViewHolder`? just use a right `Context` when creating them

Comment: @pskink I don't think I understand your comment properly. I create my views using the following code : 
`TextView tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview);`.
As I've mentioned, `itemView.getContext()` doesn't return an activity context, hence I cannot use it to start an activity, it throws an exception.

Comment: no, `findViewById` does not create any `View`, my question is: how do you create your `View` passed to `ViewHolder` constructor?

Comment: @pskink Ohh, I do that in the `onCreateViewHolder()` method and then pass the view to the `ViewHolder` constructor. So I assume adding the `onClickListener` in `onCreateViewHolder()` itself should be the same as adding it in the `ViewHolder` class?

Comment: @user2558050    
i have no idea what you are asking about... so how do you create your `View` inside `onCreateViewHolder`? what `Context` are you using there?

Comment: @user2558050 pskink is saying right. When you create a view holder, you pass a view in the constructor of view holder. So set listener on that view in OnCreateViewHolder() method.

Comment: @BhawnaRaheja Yes I was saying the exact same thing, that I could set listener on the view in `OnCreateViewHolder()` before passing it to the `ViewHolder` constructor.

Comment: @pskink In the `onCreateViewHolder()` method, I get a `ViewGroup` object as a parameter, and I use `viewgroup.getContext()` to get a `Context` object which I use to inflate the view.

Comment: @user2558050 post your `Adapter` and `ViewHolder` code

Comment: @user2558050 what does `Log.d(TAG, "ctx0: " + viewgroup.getContext().getClass())` show? and `Log.d(TAG, "ctx1: " + itemView.getContext().getClass())`?

Comment: They both return `<mypackage>.BaseApplication`.

Comment: @user2558050 that explains everything, how are you adding your `RecyclerView` then? what is yourRecyclerView.getContext().getClass() ?

Comment: @pskink Well I dont have a reference to the RecyclerView inside the Adapter, but I checked in the Activity and it also returned the exact same thing.

Comment: @user2558050 how are you adding your `RecyclerView` then?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the reference of the Activity.

```
ActivityOne.this.startActivity(intent);
```

If that doesn't work, then know that startActivity is a method of any Context.

```
class MessageViewHolderOfFriend extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final Context context;

    public  MessageViewHolderOfFriend(View v) {
        super(v);
        context = v.getContext();

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,NewActivityToRun.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

[REF:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40857102/how-start-an-activity-using-intent-inside-a-inner-static-class)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach that you can use for the same is by creating a BaseRecyclerView abstract class, and including some method to get context in there.

For example, you base class would look something like this

```
abstract class BaseRecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

private lateinit var context: Context

override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)

    context = recyclerView.context      
}

    protected fun getContext() = context
}
```

Now your Adapter class would not be extending RecyclerView.Adapter, but would extend BaseRecyclerViewAdapter class. This would look something like

```
class MyAdapter(): BaseRecyclerViewAdapter() {
    
}
```

You can now use context in MyAdapter simply by using `getContext()` which is a protected function inside the base class.

Whenever your RecyclerView is created, the base class assigns the context of the recyclerView to the variable named `context`. This `context` can now be accessed by using the `getContext()` method in the base class.