# How start an activity using Intent inside a inner static class?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, static

I have a **static** and **inner** class inside my `Activityclass`. I need to call an Activity using `Intent(context,nameOfTheNewActivity.class)` because I am trying to call an `Intent` when an item from a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` is clicked. I had to Override the `onClick` to get the position of the item was clicked using `getLayoutPosition()` (this getLayoutPosition() worked fine).

Now when I try to use Intent I have the error:

> Non-static method cannot be referenced by a static context.

I read another links from Stackoverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691702/static-startactivityintent-method). How do I call an Intent in this case of static context and inside an inner class, I.e, how do I get the context inside an inner class, and how do I solve the **fundamental ** error to do not call a non static class from  an static class?

**I tried the following before ask here:**

1. Get the context from the View using v.context but I continue with the problem - and still calling a non static method from a static context.
2. ["Static" startActivity(Intent) method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691702/static-startactivityintent-methodhttp://)
3. Delete the word static form my inner class, but did not solve and the app crashes.

**My code:**

```
public class ActivityOne extends AppCompatActivity implements
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public static class MessageViewHolderOfFriend extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {   public  MessageViewHolderOfFriend(View v) {
        super(v);
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ;

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),NewActivityToRun.class);
                startActivity(intent);//Error in this Line//
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: check this example, it will definately help https://github.com/shanwu/SimpleListViewExample

Comment: pass the context to adapter.
1. You should keep your inner class static, that's good way to prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the reference of the Activity.

```
ActivityOne.this.startActivity(intent);
```

If that doesn't work, then know that `startActivity` is a method of any Context.

```
class MessageViewHolderOfFriend extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final Context context;

    public  MessageViewHolderOfFriend(View v) {
        super(v);
        context = v.getContext();

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,NewActivityToRun.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

Ref. [How to open a different activity on recyclerView item onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767413/how-to-open-a-different-activity-on-recyclerview-item-onclick#28767516)

Regarding

> delete the word static from my inner class, but did not solve and the app crashes

You probably were closer to the solution with the removal of `static`. The app actually built. The app crashing means you should read the logcat and implement the proper solution.

Comment: `ActivityOne.this` would only work if the `MessageViewHolderOfFriend` class wasn't static.

Comment: Which is why I followed up with "if that doesn't work". Is the ViewHolder class supposed to be static anyways?

Comment: The second solution of cricket_007 worked! 1: inside the static inner class : Create a private final Context context; 2. Inside the constructor of the static inner class, after call super(v), take the context with: contex=v.getContext(); 3. inside v.setOnClickListener(...){ Intent intent = new Intent(context,NewActivityToRun.class);// to open

Answer (score 1):

You need use the Context to start SecondActivity, when you are using *context.startActivity(intent)*
and you should add 
*intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)*
before startActivity(intent)

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // method 1:
            MyInnerClass innerClass = new MyInnerClass();
            innerClass.firstLauncher(MainActivity.this);

           // method 2:
           // MyInnerClass.secondLauncher(MainActivity.this);
        }
    });
}


static class MyInnerClass {

    /**
     * member method
     */
    private void firstLauncher(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("flag_activity", "I'm 1th");
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    /**
     * static method
     */
    private static void secondLauncher(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("flag_activity", "I'm 2th");
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
}
```

SecondActivity.java :

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_msg);

    String msg = getIntent().getStringExtra("flag_activity");
    textView.setText(msg);
}
}
```

All the implements are in the ContextImpl.java file.